# How to make a color name not automatically convert to a hex value in Stylus?

Tags: colors, stylus

I am iterating a for loop with stylus preprocessor. I need color class names and color values and the hex values I get are fine but my class names are not ideal.

```
$colors = red blue green orange;
for item in $colors {
    .{"" + item} {
        color: item;
    }
}
```

and I get this compiled:

```
.#f00 {
  color: #f00;
}
.#00f {
  color: #00f;
}
.#008000 {
  color: #008000;
}
.#ffa500 {
  color: #ffa500;
}
```

but my expected result was:

```
.red {
   color: #f00; // or red
}
.blue { 
   color: #00F // or blue
}
// .. etc
```

I can imagine that there is a function for the names to remain.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can convert the original list of colors to a set of strings, this

```
$colors = 'red' 'blue' 'green' 'orange';
for item in $colors {
    .{item} {
        color: convert(item);
    }
}
```

yields

```
.red {
  color: #f00;
}
.blue {
  color: #00f;
}
.green {
  color: #008000;
}
.orange {
  color: #ffa500;
}
```

if you change `convert` to `unquote`, the hex values will get replaced with the names you supply them in the list.

Comment: String nice didn't think of that. Thank you for the tip with unquote function.